# How do I get particles to "grow" on or follow a surface (ex. below)

Tags: particles

What's a good way to have particles grow and shape a surface like below?

https://vimeo.com/203757114

I imagine this was done in MAX or C4D.

Possibly with animation nodes? I have no idea here.

To me, seems like the emitter is the object and then use a Charge with the particles having a self effect of Force.

But that doesn't seem right. I guess my goals would be:

1. Learn how to get objects to stick to an object.
2. Learn how to get particles to "push" each other out of the way along said surface.
3. Change particle color over age (probably)

Comment: Molecular add-on. There are some tutorials and questions here.

Comment: Self Effect is the way to go I think. Charge is also a good idea but I don't think is will work correctly. Rather use a force field with strength falloff over distance. Then you could also use the force field on the mesh with the mesh affector option checked. Particles didn't change color over time, but rather had different colors depending on their birth time.

Comment: You could also try particle fluids instead of self effect. I think performance will be better.